# Images from a Qt resource collection file are no longer visible

Tags: c++, qt

Suddenly the linked images in the qrc file are no longer visible, I don't know what happened.
I've already tried deleting the cmake generated files and recompiling, but it still doesn't work...

QRC FILE

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
    <file>sprites/peggle_title.png</file>
    <file>icons/peggle.ico</file>
   
    
    <file>sprites/krita.png</file>

    <file>sprites/ball.png</file>
    <file>sprites/peggles.png</file>
    <file>sprites/stage_elements.png</file>
    <file>sprites/Peggle_Fonts.png</file>
    <file>sprites/sprites.png</file>
    <file>sprites/scaricati/Peggle2PegglePS3LeftoverGraphic5.png</file>
    <file>sprites/choose_character.png</file>
    <file>sprites/mainMenu.png</file>
    <file>sprites/gameMode.png</file>
    <file>sprites/gameMode_buttons.png</file>
    <file>sprites/character_buttons.png</file>
    <file>sprites/select_single_character.png</file>
    <file>sprites/action_buttons.png</file>
    <file>sprites/character_face.png</file>
    <file>sprites/select_difficulty.png</file>
    <file>sprites/results.png</file>
    <file>sprites/results_label.png</file>


    <file>sounds/peghit.wav</file>
    
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

CMAKELISTS.txt

```
project(Peggle)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1 FATAL_ERROR)

file(GLOB my_sources *.h *.cpp *.qrc)

set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

add_executable(Peggle ${my_sources} resources.qrc)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Multimedia REQUIRED)
find_package(box2d REQUIRED)

include_directories(Box2D)

target_link_libraries(Peggle Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Multimedia box2d)
```

And for example:

```
QPixmap *title = new QPixmap(":/sprites/peggle_title.png");
```

(I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and Cmake gui)
Thanks for the help!

Comment: With Qt sometimes manually erasing all the build directory helps. With Visual Studio sometimes restarting it or rebooting whole system helps. If those simple measures do not help then check out previous commits in repo until you find one that works. Commit after it broke something. If you commit often then it is easy to see what exactly.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i was wrong to copy, thanks!

Comment: There is this entry from the CMake documentation where it tells you to link the qrc file: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/manual/cmake-qt.7.html#autorcc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/manual/cmake-qt.7.html#autorcc)

Comment: I have linked the qrc file in add_executable, however the problem persists ...

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times, users forget to run qmake. Have you tried that? Just right clicked on the project, and select "Run qmake". If yes then try deleting all of the resource files and create new resource file. Also add the qrc path in the application's pro file.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm using Visual Studio and cmake gui, so i don't know how i have to do that...

Comment: Try doing a clean build and also exit Visual Studio Community and run CMake-Gui to regenerate your project.

Comment: I did it, however the images still don't load...

Comment: If you both cleaned the build and had CMake regenerate your Visual Studio Community solution file, maybe there is some problem in your CMakeLists.txt that you are no longer using the resources.

Comment: I just posted my cmakelists.txt file, but i believe it is correct